# How to reset the value of the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, arraylist, android-listview

In My Application there is ListView and reset button.
See image for more help
[image]
Now i want to Reset the Value that i have entered in to the ListView and that should be on click of reset button.

In My that Activity i am going to add the data in to that ListView as like below:

```
    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
                    payListForEmployee = new String[] {"Tax Code","Pay period Begin","Pay Frequency","Salary/Wage per pay",
                        "Net or Gross Amount","KS Employee deduction","KS Employee contributions","Child Support deduction","Payroll giving donation"};

                    Order o[]=new Order[payListForEmployee.length];
                    System.out.println("The Length is: "+payListForEmployee.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < payListForEmployee.length; i++) 
                    {
                        o[i]=new Order();
                        o[i].setOrderName(payListForEmployee[i]);

                        //myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                        // for TAXCODE
                        if(i==0) {
                            taxCodeValue = PAYEEmployeeDetail.taxCodeFinalValue;
                            if((taxCodeValue==null)) {
                                taxCodeValue = "Please select";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(taxCodeValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());

                        }
                        // for Pay Period Frequency
                        if(i==1) {
                            //payPeriodValue = myPrefs.getString("payperiod", "12 09 2011");
                            payPeriodValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.payPeriodFinalValue;
                            if((payPeriodValue==null)) {
                                payPeriodValue = "--/--/----";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payPeriodValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for Pay frequency
                        if(i==2) {
                            //payFrequencyValue = myPrefs.getString("payfrequency", "Weekly");
                            payFrequencyValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.payFrequencyFinalValue;
                            if((payFrequencyValue==null)) {
                                payFrequencyValue = "Please select";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payFrequencyValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for salary / wage
                        if(i==3) {
                            salaryWageValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.salaryWageFinalValue;
                            if((salaryWageValue==null)||(salaryWageValue.equals(""))) {
                                salaryWageValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                salaryWageValue = "$"+salaryWageValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(salaryWageValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // For Gross / Net
                        if(i==4) {

                            o[i].setOrderStatus("Gross");
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for KS Employee Deduction
                        if(i==5) {
                            employeeDeductionValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.employeeDeductionFinalValue;
                            if((employeeDeductionValue==null)||(employeeDeductionValue.equals(""))) {
                                employeeDeductionValue = "0%";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(employeeDeductionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for KS Employee Contribution
                        if(i==6) {
                            employeeContributionValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.employeeContributionFinalValue;
                            if((employeeContributionValue==null)||(employeeContributionValue.equals(""))) {
                                employeeContributionValue = "0%";
                            }
                            else{
                                employeeContributionValue = employeeContributionValue+"%";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(employeeContributionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for Child Support Deduction
                        if(i==7) {
                            childSupportDeductionValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.childSupportDeductionFinalValue;
                            if((childSupportDeductionValue==null)||(childSupportDeductionValue.equals(""))) {
                                childSupportDeductionValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                childSupportDeductionValue = "$"+childSupportDeductionValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(childSupportDeductionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for Payroll giving donation
                        if(i==8) {
                            payrollDonationValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.payrollDonationFinalValue;
                            if((payrollDonationValue==null)||(payrollDonationValue.equals(""))) {
                                payrollDonationValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                payrollDonationValue = "$"+payrollDonationValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payrollDonationValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        m_orders.add(o[i]);
}
```

And it is Display by the getView method. 
now what should i have to do if i want to reset all the value on click of the reset button ? Should i have to finish and call that activity with the new one ?
How to make it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your adapter, I guess you are simply extending ArrayAdapter. In that case you can just call the method `clear()` on it.

Comment: So Should i have to call the clear() on Reset Button ? But i want to Clear only the Blue Colour value not the Left one Text Value then ???

Comment: Thanks FOr the Anser. But doing that i got all the item clear. Instead of that i want to clear only Blue Color value to be reset. And the code by which i am adding that value is listed on the question.

Comment: Ok I got the Sollution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: will you please help me little more ? What will be called if i am coming back to this activity from the detail activity ? as in this activity i am calling finction getOrder() where i am going to set all the values. I want to call it if i come back to this activity from the detail activity. Thanks.

Comment: Your listview will be there but if you need to refresh some data you can put your logic in the onResume method.

Comment: Yes, I have done it and it works great. Now i want another help if you can help me. Wait...  I am putting question on stack for it. And thanks a lot again.

Comment: Please see this question and help me for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633236/android-how-to-implement-such-operation-for-android-listview