# Android: How to Implement such operation for Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

My Application has like below functionality:

[image: See Image]

I have Done to set the Values with the custom adapter. but now i want to implement the functionality as like add another data, delete showing data, go to next data and back to previous data. In all that functionality only the Blue Values should be change. (that is the orderStatus in code). Left One Value (orderName()) should remain the same. Then how to implement that ?

If i am adding the new data then that should be temporary stored as i want to show that data in to report.

In My Application i am going to add data first time AS like below code:

getOrder function to set the Value of the OrderName and OrderStatus.

```
    public void getOrders(){
        try{
//              if(employee)
//              {
                    System.out.println("You are in Employee");
                    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
                    payListForEmployee = new String[] {"Tax Code","Pay period Begin","Pay Frequency","Salary/Wage per pay",
                        "Net or Gross Amount","KS Employee deduction","KS Employee contributions","Child Support deduction","Payroll giving donation"};

                    Order o[]=new Order[payListForEmployee.length];
                    System.out.println("The Length is: "+payListForEmployee.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < payListForEmployee.length; i++) 
                    {
                        o[i]=new Order();
                        o[i].setOrderName(payListForEmployee[i]);

                        //myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                        // for TAXCODE
                        if(i==0) {
                            taxCodeValue = PAYEEmployeeDetail.taxCodeFinalValue;
                            if((taxCodeValue==null)) {
                                taxCodeValue = "Please select";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(taxCodeValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());

                        }
                        // for Pay Period Frequency
                        if(i==1) {
                            //payPeriodValue = myPrefs.getString("payperiod", "12 09 2011");
                            payPeriodValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.payPeriodFinalValue;
                            if((payPeriodValue==null)) {
                                payPeriodValue = "--/--/----";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payPeriodValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for Pay frequency
                        if(i==2) {
                            //payFrequencyValue = myPrefs.getString("payfrequency", "Weekly");
                            payFrequencyValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.payFrequencyFinalValue;
                            if((payFrequencyValue==null)) {
                                payFrequencyValue = "Please select";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payFrequencyValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for salary / wage
                        if(i==3) {
                            salaryWageValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.salaryWageFinalValue;
                            if((salaryWageValue==null)||(salaryWageValue.equals(""))) {
                                salaryWageValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                salaryWageValue = "$"+salaryWageValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(salaryWageValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // For Gross / Net
                        if(i==4) {

                            o[i].setOrderStatus("Gross");
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for KS Employee Deduction
                        if(i==5) {
                            employeeDeductionValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.employeeDeductionFinalValue;
                            if((employeeDeductionValue==null)||(employeeDeductionValue.equals(""))) {
                                employeeDeductionValue = "0%";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(employeeDeductionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for KS Employee Contribution
                        if(i==6) {
                            employeeContributionValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.employeeContributionFinalValue;
                            if((employeeContributionValue==null)||(employeeContributionValue.equals(""))) {
                                employeeContributionValue = "0%";
                            }
                            else{
                                employeeContributionValue = employeeContributionValue+"%";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(employeeContributionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for Child Support Deduction
                        if(i==7) {
                            childSupportDeductionValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.childSupportDeductionFinalValue;
                            if((childSupportDeductionValue==null)||(childSupportDeductionValue.equals(""))) {
                                childSupportDeductionValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                childSupportDeductionValue = "$"+childSupportDeductionValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(childSupportDeductionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for Payroll giving donation
                        if(i==8) {
                            payrollDonationValue =  PAYEEmployeeDetail.payrollDonationFinalValue;
                            if((payrollDonationValue==null)||(payrollDonationValue.equals(""))) {
                                payrollDonationValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                payrollDonationValue = "$"+payrollDonationValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payrollDonationValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        m_orders.add(o[i]);
                        //lv.invalidate();
//                      System.out.println("==> TaXCode Value: "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.taxCodeFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> PAyPeriod Value: "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.payPeriodFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> PayFrequency Value: "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.payFrequencyFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Salary/Wage Value: "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.salaryWageFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Gross/Net Value "+"STATIC VALUE = GROSS");
//                      System.out.println("==> Employee Deduction Value "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.employeeDeductionFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Employee Contribution Value "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.employeeContributionFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Child Support Deduction Value "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.childSupportDeductionFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> PayRoll Donation Value "+PAYEEmployeeDetail.payrollDonationFinalValue);
//                      
                    }
//              }
//              else
//              {
//                  System.out.println("You Are in Employer");
//                  m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
//                  
//                  payListForEmployer = new String[] {"Tax Code","Pay period Begin","Pay Frequency","Salary/Wage per pay",
//                          "Net or Gross Amount","KiwiSaver Member","Employee Deduction","Employee Contributions",
//                          "Complying Fund Member","Fund Contribution","ESCT Tax Rate","Child Support Deduction","Payroll giving donation"};
//                  
//                  System.out.println("The Length is: "+payListForEmployer.length);
//                  
//                  Order o[]=new Order[payListForEmployer.length];
//                  for (int i = 0; i < payListForEmployer.length; i++) 
//                  {
//                      o[i]=new Order();
//                      o[i].setOrderName(payListForEmployer[i]);
//                      o[i].setOrderStatus("Pending");
//                      m_orders.add(o[i]);
//                  }
//              }

                Thread.sleep(100);
                Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
         runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){

                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                    m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
            }
           // m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
};
```

And Creating and calling the thread like this:

```
 viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };

    thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
```

So Will please help me to give logic for that or give some code that can help me in this to implement that functionality.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of your question

> I have Done to set the Values with the custom adapter. but now i want
>   to implement the functionality as like add another data, delete
>   showing data, go to next data and back to previous data. In all that
>   functionality only the Blue Values should be change. (that is the
>   orderStatus in code). Left One Value (orderName()) should remain the
>   same. Then how to implement that ?

Here is my answer in few steps and assuming that you are passing your list values in var 'A':

**1.** You should extend `BaseAdapter` in your `custom adapter` of the list.

**2.** Set your initial values to `A` and pass it to the `adapter` and `set it to the listview`.

**3.** Now if you want to add some more values then `add it in your var A` and `call the` `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will reflect your new values to the list.

**4.** If you want to show next values then also set the appropriate values in A and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**5.** If you want to delete then `setOnItemClickListener()` to your list and on click remove the values from the `A` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**Note:** To save the list values you can use SQLite. You can follow this tutorial over [lisview](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: I dont want to save the values to the database. but i am going to view all the values in to report thats why i want all the value. .

Comment: If you don't want to save the values then don't save but make sure you have all the values with yourself for the report..

Comment: ok. So Should i have use ArrayList or HashMap to implement it ?